# Using Shopify Store Customer Account to Authenticate Node JS API

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I'm building a NodeJS API + Android/IOS Apps connecting to that API.

Additionally, I have a Shopify store where customers register and purchase products.

Now, I need to set up auth flow on these mobile APPS, which will redirect to the Shopify store, authenticate using customer account credentials, allow that customer to log in with APP, and allow API access with that authentication.

[image]

API Auth layer developed with JWT authentication for the moment which is working without shopify interaction.

Is there anyone who has done something like this with Shopify customer accounts?

Comment: You don't get access to Shopify customer account credentials. If you install an App in the store with permissions to read customer accounts, you get their names, addresses etc, but you never get access to their credentials.

Comment: Hey David, Thanks for the comment, Will that be possible to use Shopify store as we do with google auth? users will redirect and authentication will happen on shopify store. then redirect to APP on successful authentication

Comment: You cannot redirect to some URL when you login to Shopify. Nope.